# how to set margin only between cells in zurb foundation grid?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

how to set gutters (margins) only between cells in [foundation grid](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#gutters) (not to have left margin before first cell and right margin after last cell)?

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: i think that my question is clear! when i use grid-margin-x class, foundation creates margin around all the cells but i want to remove left margin before the first cell and right margin after the last cell

Comment: then just remove the left-margin from the left cell and right-margin from the right cell..

Comment: i know, but i want to find out if foundation itself has a solution for this case